# How to Permit 4-Level Deep Index Entries (was, "Why are Index Entries Rejected?"}

Tags: indexing

I have marked index entries in a document and get the following when I run \makeindex:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2020] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file 2023_scl_002 copy.idx....done (171 entries accepted, 26 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (1400 comparisons).
Generating output file 2023_scl_002 copy.ind....done (240 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in 2023_scl_002 copy.ind.
Transcript written in 2023_scl_002 copy.ilg.
```

Why were 26 entries rejected? How can I determine the reasons for rejection?

Edit: I looked at the *.ilg file and saw this:

```
!! Input index error (file = 2023_scl_002 copy.idx, line = 157):
   -- Extra `!' at position 46 of first argument.
```

So I went to the *.idx file and saw this entry:

```
\indexentry{Joint Stock Company!General Assembly!Meetings!Frequency}{81}
```

I don't see the problem. Are four levels prohibited? If so, how can I include them?

2nd Edit: Looks like 4 levels isn't permitted under \makeindex. Is there a package that permits 4 levels? Or five?

@egreg:

3rd Edit:

So to use xindex, you have to:

1. Run LaTeX once.
2. Run LaTeX again to get the ToC.
3. Run `xindex` against the LaTeX file
4. Run LaTeX again to get a pdf with the xindex-generated index.

4th Edit:

Running `\makeindex` in order to use `xindex` still rejects four level deep entries.

Comment: What is in `2023_scl_002 copy.ilg`? Just a copy of this text? Otherwise you probably have to do some digging to figure out where the problems are. It can be that the index text contains incorrect use of special chars. Without example code we cannot say much.

Comment: @daleif: Please see edit.

Comment: It is probably a limitation in `makeindex`. I tend to use `texindy/xindy` and it does not have such limitations. Though do remember that having these very deep indices makes them hard to read.

Comment: You can try `xindex` instead of `makeindex`, which supports four levels. Not more.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need four levels, you can try `xindex` instead of `makeindex`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[imakeidx]{xindex}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\subsubsubitem}{\@idxitem\hspace*{40\p@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

Abc

\index{Joint Stock Company}
\index{Joint Stock Company!General Assembly}
\index{Joint Stock Company!General Assembly!Meetings}
\index{Joint Stock Company!General Assembly!Meetings!Frequency}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Running this with `pdflatex -shell-escape` produces the four level index.

[image]

Five levels? It *can* be done.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[imakeidx]{xindex}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\subsubsubitem}{\@idxitem\hspace*{40\p@}}
\providecommand{\subsubsubsubitem}{\@idxitem\hspace*{50\p@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

Abc

\index{Joint Stock Company}
\index{Joint Stock Company!General Assembly}
\index{Joint Stock Company!General Assembly!Meetings}
\index{Joint Stock Company!General Assembly!Meetings!Frequency}
\index{Joint Stock Company!General Assembly!Meetings!Frequency!Gosh}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Deleting the package ``\usepackage(makeidx)`` throws an ``Undefined control sequence.<argument> \imki@jobame @idxfile`` at the last line of the document. Keeping the ``makeidx`` package and adding ``\usepackage[imakeidx]{xindex}`` throws the same error.

Comment: Looks like to run properly, ``\usepackage[imakeidx]{xindex}`` has to precede ``\makeindex``. However, when running ``\makeindex``, the fourth level entries continue to be rejected.

Comment: BTW, if this needs calling an external shell (no terminal shell pops up) command, then the solution doesn't work under TexShop and TexLive 2020.

Comment: ``\makeindex`` still identifies errors; these are not picked up by running ``pdflatex`` from the command prompt.